# Some CAN Identifiers corrupted on STM32G0

Tags: stm32, can

In the attached example I am using `0x1dedbeef` as the CAN ID but when read back using a Kvaser the ID is `0x1FEFBEFF`. This corruption happens for some, but not all IDs...

Very strange, any ideas?

fdcan settings are as follows:

```
  hfdcan1.Instance = FDCAN1;
  hfdcan1.Init.ClockDivider = FDCAN_CLOCK_DIV1;
  hfdcan1.Init.FrameFormat = FDCAN_FRAME_FD_NO_BRS;
  hfdcan1.Init.Mode = FDCAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hfdcan1.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;
  hfdcan1.Init.TransmitPause = DISABLE;
  hfdcan1.Init.ProtocolException = DISABLE;
  hfdcan1.Init.NominalPrescaler = 4;
  hfdcan1.Init.NominalSyncJumpWidth = 1;
  hfdcan1.Init.NominalTimeSeg1 = 11;
  hfdcan1.Init.NominalTimeSeg2 = 4;
  hfdcan1.Init.DataPrescaler = 1;
  hfdcan1.Init.DataSyncJumpWidth = 4;
  hfdcan1.Init.DataTimeSeg1 = 11;
  hfdcan1.Init.DataTimeSeg2 = 4;
  hfdcan1.Init.StdFiltersNbr = 0;
  hfdcan1.Init.ExtFiltersNbr = 0;
  hfdcan1.Init.TxFifoQueueMode = FDCAN_TX_FIFO_OPERATION;
```

Header:

```
  FDCAN_TxHeaderTypeDef txHeader;
  txHeader.IdType = FDCAN_EXTENDED_ID;
  txHeader.Identifier = 0x1dedbeef;
  txHeader.DataLength = FDCAN_DLC_BYTES_4;
```

Transmission:

```
HAL_FDCAN_AddMessageToTxFifoQ(&hfdcan1, &txHeader, uid8a);
```

Comment: Is it classic CAN or CAN FD? Also this problem could be anywhere, not necessarily in the code you've posted. Also, always read the MCU errata especially for somewhat new peripherals like those with CAN FD support.

Comment: @Lundin this running in FD no BRS, as shown in the code example. This happens with this being the only code other than the filling of the uid8a array. Just checked and it reads incorrectly even when read from a duplicate of the same device, so it is not due to bit timing issues.

Comment: @Lundin There's also nothing relevant in the Errata